# How to set a default value to an input of FileType in Symfony/Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, md5

Just like the TextType and other types that have a default attribute of value => $myValue. I am trying to set a user's existing image from the database as default when trying to update user's picture in an update form. I have been reading the Doctrine Assets  documentation but no luck yet https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html

```
$form =$this->createFormBuilder($contact)

   ->add('picture', FileType::class, ['required'=>false, 'label' => 'Add 
        Profile picture (jpg file)'])

    ->add('firstname', TextType::class, array('attr'=>
       array('value'=>'mydefaultvalue','class' => 'form-control')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the value inside the object:

```
$contact->setFirstname('Primo');
$form =$this->createFormBuilder($contact)
   ->add('picture', FileType::class, ['required'=>false, 'label' => 'Add 
      Profile picture (jpg file)'])
   ->add('firstname', TextType::class, array('attr'=>
      array('value'=>'mydefaultvalue','class' => 'form-control')))
```